# Add a dot (.) automatically while typing in an asp.net textbox (format textbox To 2 Decimal Places)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox to get user input amount of money, so I want a dot (.) will always be added in front of the last 2 digits automatically as soon as user started to type in the textbox (not after they finished typing but on the go).

For example:

- User moved the mouse to the textbox and typed '1' => textbox is
  automatically displaying as 0.01
- User typed '12' => textbox
  displaying as 0.12
- User typed '123' => textbox displaying as 1.23
- User typed '1234' => textbox displaying as 12.24
- User typed '123456'
  => textbox displaying as 1234.56 and so on...

So the textbox will always be 2 decimal places.
My JS is really lacking now (I am trying to improve it) I know the logic is really not hard but I am having difficulties with JS syntax and functions. I also tried the Ajax toolkit Masked Edit Extender but there is a bug with ASP.NET 4.5 (where the mask not go away if textbox lost focus)

My existing code only add a dot and 00 at the end of the number and after people move the mouse away (textbox lost focus), I really need help here. (***I already have a JS filter function so that user can only type in digits***)

```
<!-- BEGIN Add dot (.) to the end of amount -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppendDot(textbox) {
        var text = textbox.value;
        document.getElementById("<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>").value = "";
        if (text.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            document.getElementById("<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>").value = text + ".00";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>").value = text;
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- END Add dot (.) to the end of amount -->

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" MaxLength="12" onchange="AppendDot(this);" />
```

---

**Note for the answer**: the answer from GibboK below is an excellent hint and leaded me to the solution, so I selected it as answer.
My approach based on GibboK's answer:

- using onkeyup instead of onblur: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" MaxLength="12" onkeyup="process();" />`
- in the 'process()' JS function, perform following steps:
- First of all: `var amount = document.getElementById("<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>").value;`
- Then Remove the dot of the `amount` (so for example 0.01 => 001, 00.12 => 0012, 12.34 => 1234 and so on)
- Remove all the zeros 0 at the front of the `amount` (so for example 001 => 1, 0012 => 12, 0102 => 102, 1234 => still 1234 and so on)
- Apply the logic in the GibboK's answer:

  ```
      var len = amount.length;
      var newAmount;

      if (len == 1) {
          newAmount = '0.0' + amount;
      } else if (len == 2) {
          newAmount = '0.' + amount;
      } else if (len == 3) {
          newAmount = amount.slice(0, 1) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
      } else if (len == 4) {
          newAmount = amount.slice(0, 2) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
      }
      else if (len > 4) {
          newAmount = amount.slice(0, amount.length - 2) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
      }

      document.getElementById("<%=txtAmount.ClientID %>").value = newAmount;
  ```

Comment: why dont you try using Ajax MaskedEdit https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedEdit%20Control&referringTitle=Tutorials

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: I gave it a tried but it is bugged (I mentioned) and the format is pre-defined, for example (9999.99) - some user only enter 5 or10 dollar, some enter 20 thousand dollars, some enter 100 thousand, so it is not really what I want ( I dont want to set it 9,999,999.99 it will makes user confused, more importantly is the bug it having)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help you with the logic. In this example I am suing onblur to process the data. You can consider using onkeyup and onkeydown. Hope it helps!

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function process() {
    var elm = document.getElementsByName('amount')[0];
    var amount = elm.value,
        len = amount.length,
        newAmount;

        if(amount == '') {
            return;
        }
        if(isNaN(amount) == true) {
            alert('Value is not a valid number!');
            elm.value = '';
            return;
        }

    if(len == 1) {
        newAmount = '0.0' + amount;
    } else if(len == 2) {
        newAmount = '0.' + amount;
    } else if(len == 3) {
        newAmount = amount.slice(0,1) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
    } else if(len == 4) {
        newAmount = amount.slice(0,2) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
    }
    else if(len > 4) {
        newAmount = amount.slice(0, amount.length - 2) + '.' + amount.slice(-2);
    }

    elm.value = newAmount ? newAmount : '';

 /* 
    User moved the mouse to the textbox and typed '1' => textbox is automatically displaying as 0.01
    User typed '12' => textbox displaying as 0.12
    User typed '123' => textbox displaying as 1.23
    User typed '1234' => textbox displaying as 12.24
    User typed '123456' => textbox displaying as 1234.56 and so on...
 */

};

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" onblur="process();"><br>
</form>

 </body>
 </html>
```